# Reactive textfield signal doesn't fire on delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I have a `UITextField` and try to react to `textField.text` changes:

```
self.textField.delegate = self;
[self.textField.rac_textSignal map:^id(NSString *text) {
     return @(YES); // breakpoint here
}];
```

I'm running through the [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62699/reactivecocoa-tutorial-pt1) to learn `ROC`. I've noticed, that the block is being called when I type new character, but not when I delete old character. How to fix it..? I want the action to be called when I delete previous character.

---

Eg: on the left what is inside `textField.text`, on right - what's happening:

- `a` - hits breakpoint
- `ab` - hits breakpoint
- `abc` - hits breakpoint
- `ab` - nothing happens

---

*Disclaimer*: As I'm just learning this framework and don't want to make first steps on different version, i'm using same version of `ROC` as in the tutorial:

```
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '2.1.8'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out that this code works well instead of yours.

```
[self.usernameTextField.rac_textSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
  NSLog(@"%@", x);
}];
```

**The difference is that my code have an `subscribeNext:` method call.** 
Basic concept here is that you need **subscription** to execute you code. `map:` is the operator that changes input data only when data arrived. `subscribeNext:` / `subscribeCompleted:` / `subscribeError:` are the root cause of the forcing signals to send data to the chain in the ReactiveCocoa.

Probably you should read the [official framework overview](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/Legacy/FrameworkOverview.md#sequences) from the ReactiveCocoa team.

**UPDATE:**

For the current situation applying `subscribeNext` to the end will fix issue:

```
[[self.usernameTextField.rac_textSignal 
   map:^id(id x) { 
     NSLog(@"%@", x);
     return x;
}] 
   subscribeNext:^(id x) { 
     NSLog(@"%@", x); 
}];
```

Comment: Hm, each time I update the text, I receive whole string in `map` function. In my opinion, during char deletion the whole string also changes, so also the `map` function should be called. Just as you said: _changes input data only when data arrived_, why the data doesn't arrive? The data changed, text changed. Atm I don't understand this part in the documentation unfortunately. Your answer is ok, so I'm marking it as valid, but I'd be grateful for explanation of my question - I still don't understand _why_ the data doesn't arrive to the `map` function.

Comment: @Vive, you should not rely on the chain without subscription, [[self.usernameTextField.rac_textSignal map:^id(id x) {
  NSLog(@"%@", x);
}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
  NSLog(@"%@", x);
}];

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot :)